# Removing a header and footer from text output with PDFminer

Tags: python, pdf

I use PDFminer to extract text from a PDF, then I reopen the output file to remove an 8 line header and 8 line footer. Is there a more efficient way to remove the header/footer, either in place or without re-opening/closing the file? Please mention general best practices I did not follow.

```
# convert PDF to text
def write_txt(pdf):
    outfile = pdf.split("_")[4] + "_" + pdf.split("_")[1] + "_" + \
        pdf.split("_")[0] + ".txt"
    pagenos = set([2,3])

    codec = 'utf-8'
    caching = True
    laparams = LAParams()

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager(caching=caching)
    outfp = file(outfile, 'w+')
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(pdf, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    outfp.close()

    # remove header/footer
    with open(outfile, 'r') as txtin:
        lines = txtin.read().splitlines(True)
    with open(outfile, 'w') as txtout:
        txtout.writelines(lines[8:-8])

    return outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This line performs the same string splitting 3 times:

> ```
> outfile = pdf.split("_")[4] + "_" + pdf.split("_")[1] + "_" + \
>     pdf.split("_")[0] + ".txt"
> ```

It would be better to split only once, and also to replace the messy string concatenation:

```
parts = pdf.split("_")
outfile = '{}_{}_{}.txt'.format(parts[4], parts[1], parts[0])
```

---

The variables could have better names.
When I see "pdf",
it makes me think of a PDF object.
But in this code it's just the filename string.
So I'd call it `pdf_filename`.

---

I don't have this Python library you're using,
and I'm just wondering if you could rewrite all those resources that you close manually (`fp`, `device`, `outfp`) to use the `with` syntax instead like you used for `txtin` and `txtout`.
If that's not possible with this library, then nevermind.

Comment: Even if they aren't implemented as context managers, the OP can import [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) and use that.